# message:"SSLv3 methods disabled"

Tags: node.js, https, openssl

Как включить поддержку SSLv3/TLS1 в NodeJS 13?
Требуется получать данные с сервера по HTTPS которые использует устаревшие протоколы.

```
  var options = {
      url : "https://remote_ip:remote_port/req",
      agentOptions: {
        securityOptions: 'SSLv3_method'
    },
     secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method' 
    };

    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); 
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      console.log('body:', body);       
    } );
```

Текст ошибки

```
TypeError: SSLv3 methods disabled
index.js:25
code:"ERR_TLS_INVALID_PROTOCOL_METHOD"
message:"SSLv3 methods disabled"
stack:"TypeError: SSLv3 methods disabled\n    at new SecureContext (_tls_common.js:74:16)\n    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:101:13)\n    at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1450:48)\n    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:124:22)\n    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:270:26)\n    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:229:10)\n    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:293:16)\n    at Object.request (https.js:308:10)\n    at Request.start (/root/httpsproxy/node_modules/request/request.js:751:32)\n    at Request.end (/root/httpsproxy/node_modules/request/request.js:1511:10)"
```

Comment: [Разработчики говорят, что никак](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3695)

Comment: а какие старые версии nodejs и библиотеки поддерживали этот стандарт?